# Using ajax to constantly refresh php output from div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have php includes in different divs, how can i use ajax to constantly refresh the data outputted from the php file every second, I have multiple things that need to refresh, one per div

Comment: And what you have tried yet apart from posting this question on SO?

Comment: I have tried methods but they did not let me have all the divs and php files to refresh in one function

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the javascript function `settimeout`
2. In the `setimeout` function, perform the ajax request
3. Fill the `div` element with the results from the ajax request
4. Again, use the `settimeout` function in the ajax response and perform the step 2 and 3.

Comment: Please don't ask for upvotes/accepts as it's not considered as constructive. See: [Is it acceptable to ask for upvote/accept in an answer when submitting it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it)

Comment: I'm planning out the design for a real-time game, and I was wondering, how often should the `setimeout` be? I want it to be real-time, but would having a delay of 0 lag up the server?

Answer (score 0):

send a ajax request per second.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        // param
    });
}, 1000);
```